# Set max quantity based on a custom field in a Product Variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product-variations

I am trying to set a variation's maximum quantity allowance based on the value of a one of its custom fields.

Everything is good - the code is working below, however rather than `$quantity = round(9/3);` I want the value to be `$quantity = round($quantity/$weight);`

The issue I am having (and have had numerous times in the past with other functions) is that I can't for the life of me seem to pull the correct `'Custom_Field'` data. Everything I try returns either `boolean false` or `string Length(0)`. When I do a `var_dump($variation_ID)` I get a ton of data, but my custom field is not there.

This is strange, because the data is pulled in other functions I have - but not in this situation and I can't figure out why.

```
// On single product pages
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'customizing_available_variation', 10, 3  );
    function customizing_available_variation( $args, $product_id, $variation_id ) {


    $product = wc_get_product ( $product_id );
    $weight = get_post_meta( $variation_ID, 'custom_field', true );

    $product_stock = $product_id->get_stock_quantity();
    var_dump($variation_id);

    $quantity = round(9/3);

    if( is_woocommerce() ){
        $args['max_qty'] = $quantity;
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`woocommerce_available_variation`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product_Variable.html#328) passes three arguments, the third one being a [`WC_Product_Variation`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variation.html) (that's why you're getting a ton of data when `var_dump`-ing it).

You've named your third argument `$variation_id`, which probably led you to treating it as a post/product id.

Meaning, you're trying to pass a `WC_Product_Variation` as an id to [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/):

```php
$weight = get_post_meta( $variation_ID, 'custom_field', true );
```

You're also doing the same thing for the second argument (which is the product, not the product id).

You just have to get the variation id and pass that instead:

```php
/**
 * Customize available variation
 *
 * @param array $args
 * @param WC_Product_Variable $product
 * @param WC_Product_Variation $variation
 */
function customizing_available_variation( $args, $product, $variation ) {
    $weight = get_post_meta( $variation->get_id(), 'custom_field', true );
    // …
}
```

Comment: That did it man! Amazing, thank you so much!

Any recommendations for a good place to read up on arguments in wordpress? This seems to be something I really need to get a better grasp of. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChazPierce Happy to help! For WooCommerce specifically you can search each hook in the [Hook Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) and read their source for their arguments and usage. For WordPress in general, check the [Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/) and the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/).